# Using ggplot2 with Julia pluto notebook

Tags: ggplot2, julia

I am working with a Pluto.jl notebook.  I would like to use the ggplot2 R library to make some plots.

Following [this example](https://avt.im/blog/2018/03/23/R-packages-ggplot-in-julia),  if I run the following code in the Julia REPL then I can get a ggplot2 graph output.

```
using RCall
@rlibrary ggplot2
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(v = [3,4,5], w = [5,6,7], x = [1,2,3], y = [4,5,6], z = [1,1,2])
ggplot(df, aes(x=:x,y=:y)) + geom_line()
```

Now, when I use the same code in a pluto.jl notebook (with each line being a separate cell), then I get the following error message:

[image]

Is there a way to get the ggplot2 image to appear inside the pluto notebook?

Similarly, if I just enter  `ggplot()` into a cell, I get the same error, but `ggplot not defined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@library` Pluto.jl seems to be unable to find the R package.

However Pluto can handle this format:

```
@rimport ggplot2 as ggplot2
```

[image]

I managed to see the picture after clicking the "play" button 3 or 4 times. That is the end of good news - the Plut-RCall integration is kind of unstable. The graph shows in a separate Window that seems to hang - this is perhaps a story for opening an issue.

However what you can try to do is to save the image to a file and than visualize it:

```
begin
    ggplot2.ggplot(df, ggplot2.aes(x=:x, y=:y)) +  ggplot2.geom_line()
    ggplot2.ggsave("myplot.png")
    im1 = Images.load("myplot.png")
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, it is possible to override `Base.show` manually (see [Pluto.jl/sample/test1.jl](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl/blob/master/sample/test1.jl)) with

```
function Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"image/png", p::RObject{VecSxp})
    (path, _) = mktemp()
    R"ggsave($path, plot=$p, device = 'png')"
    im = read(path)
    rm(path)
    write(io, im)
end
```

After that, cells which output anything of the type `RObject{VecSxp}` will show a PNG image:

[image: Pluto notebook]

Comment: Small warning: Other methods are also `RObject{VecSxp}` but not plots, e.g. lists. Therefore, overloading `show` breaks how those other objects are shown.